# Block directory in magento

Tags: magento, block

I am new to Magento. I just want to know in which situation we write the code in Block directory? Why we cannt write same code in Controllers? 
I read articles for this but does not get the answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mathias Müller .... rather than reducing points, answers will be really appreciated.

Comment: I did not downvote your question - but your question deserves the negative vote. You do not really explain the problem you are facing.

Comment: Its pretty clear..I just want to know use of Block directory in Magento in detail...I am not facing any problem just want to understand properly..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ [Magento for Developers: Part 4 - Magento Layouts, Blocks and Templates](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates)

> Unlike many popular MVC systems, Magento's Action Controller does not
>   pass a data object to the view or set properties on the view object
>   (with a few exceptions). Instead, the View component directly
>   references system models to get the information it needs for display.
>
> One consequence of this design decision is that the View has been
>   separated into Blocks and Templates. Blocks are PHP objects, Templates
>   are "raw" PHP files (with a .phtml extension) that contain a mix of
>   HTML and PHP (where PHP is used as a templating language). Each Block
>   is tied to a single Template file. Inside a phtml file, PHP's $this
>   keyword will contain a reference to the Template's Block object

Comment: thanks RS...now getting some idea

Answer (score 0):

We write the code in Block directory for creating blocks.
Example: we need to show a block at the left sidebar. controller doesn't need for this.

Comment: thanks John..appreciated